# Suite CRM , Creating users Issues

Tags: suitecrm

MY issue that when am trying to create a normal user from Suite CRM ( User Management ) after pressing save , the server getting loading without any response and in the same time another active user getting msgs ( Cannot connect to data base ) until i need to restart the server ?

Comment: can you check suitecrm and server logs for the possible reason for the issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
    Wed Sep 11 11:33:41 2019 [30147][8dfa3f2c-e526-6242-6732-585643139abd][INFO] Query: SELECT  alerts.*  , jt0.user_name modified_by_name , jt0.created_by modified_by_name_owner  , 'Users' modified_by_name_mod , jt1.user_name created_by_name , jt1.created_by created_by_name_owner  , 'Users' created_by_name_mod , jt2.user_name assigned_user_name , jt2.created_by assigned_user_name_owner  , 'Users' assigned_user_name_mod FROM alerts   LEFT JOIN  users jt0 ON alerts.modified_user_id=jt0.id AND jt0.deleted=0

 AND jt0.deleted=0  LEFT JOIN  users jt1 ON alerts.created_by=jt1.id AND jt1.deleted=0

 AND jt1.deleted=0  LEFT JOIN  users jt2 ON alerts.assigned_user_id=jt2.id AND jt2.deleted=0

 AND jt2.deleted=0 where (alerts.assigned_user_id = '8dfa3f2c-e526-6242-6732-585643139abd' AND is_read != '1') AND alerts.deleted=0
Wed Sep 11 11:33:41 2019 [30147][8dfa3f2c-e526-6242-6732-585643139abd][INFO] Query Execution Time:0.0002281665802002
Wed Sep 11 11:33:41 2019 [30147][8dfa3f2c-e526-6242-6732-585643139abd][DEBUG] process_full_list_query: result is mysqli_result Object
(
    [current_field] => 0
    [field_count] => 23
    [lengths] => 
    [num_rows] => 0
    [type] => 0
)

Wed Sep 11 11:33:41 2019 [30147][8dfa3f2c-e526-6242-6732-585643139abd][WARN] Saving error level. Try to remove the error_reporting() function from your code.
Wed Sep 11 11:33:41 2019 [30147][8dfa3f2c-e526-6242-6732-585643139abd][WARN] Pop error level. Try to remove the error_reporting() function from your code.
Wed Sep 11 11:33:41 2019 [30147][8dfa3f2c-e526-6242-6732-585643139abd][DEBUG] Hook called: ::server_round_trip
Wed Sep 11 11:33:41 2019 [30147][8dfa3f2c-e526-6242-6732-585643139abd][DEBUG] Calling MySQLi::disconnect()
```

Comment: instead of posting it as an answer, update your question with this info.